# IsInRole() Method is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create authentication login based on this article: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2905/Role-based-Security-with-Forms-Authentication
All works fine, I can log in based on user, but I am having problem with IsInRole method. If I log in in any role the Adminlink still appear to all users. I just did almost all the same as the above article.

The code of Global.asax

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
                {
                    FormsIdentity id =
                        (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;

                    // Get the stored user-data, in this case, our roles
                    string userData = ticket.UserData;
                    string[] roles = userData.Split(',');
                    HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The code of Web.config

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="databasestring" connectionString="Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms name="MYWEBAPP.ASPXAUTH"
         loginUrl="login.aspx"
         protection="All"
           path="/"/>
     </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
       </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <location path="admin">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <!-- Order and case are important below -->
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="librarian">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <!-- Order and case are important below -->
        <allow roles="Librarian"/>
          <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

The code of login button:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            // Initialize FormsAuthentication, for what it's worth
            FormsAuthentication.Initialize();

            // Create our connection and command objects
            SqlConnection conn =
             new SqlConnection("Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT UserType FROM users WHERE UserID=@UserID AND UserPassword=@UserPassword";

            // Fill our parameters
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 64).Value = UserID.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserPassword", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = UserPassword.Value; // Or "sha1"

            // Execute the command
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                // Create a new ticket used for authentication
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                   1, // Ticket version
                   UserID.Value, // Username associated with ticket
                   DateTime.Now, // Date/time issued
                   DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), // Date/time to expire
                   true, // "true" for a persistent user cookie
                   reader.GetString(0), // User-data, in this case the roles
                   FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);// Path cookie valid for

                // Encrypt the cookie using the machine key for secure transport
                string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(
                   FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, // Name of auth cookie
                   hash); // Hashed ticket

                // Set the cookie's expiration time to the tickets expiration time
                if (ticket.IsPersistent) cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;

                // Add the cookie to the list for outgoing response
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                // Redirect to requested URL, or homepage if no previous page
                // requested
                string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["/WebForm2.aspx"];
                if (returnUrl == null) returnUrl = "/WebForm2.aspx";

                // Don't call FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage since it
                // could
                // replace the authentication ticket (cookie) we just added
                Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // Never tell the user if just the username is password is incorrect.
                // That just gives them a place to start, once they've found one or
                // the other is correct!
                ErrorLabel.Text = "Username / password incorrect. Please try again.";
                ErrorLabel.Visible = true;
            }

            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
 }
```

The code of WebForm2.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            AdminLink.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The "almost" is probably the problem.  We would need to see some code to figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication typically uses cookies, and if so, then a full server\client round trip is required to get full dependable data.  Are you authenticating the user performing a round trip before checking for role status?

Also, how\where are you setting the "adminlink" visibility properties?  Are you using a LoginView control, or some other means of showing\hiding this data?  Please provide some basic code samples.

---

Response to edit:
I don't see where you're setting this link's visibility to false anywhere.  Add that logic to your else in your conditional statement.. and\or set "visible=false" in your HTML markup and see if that fixes it.

If that doesn't fix it, have you set a breakpoint to see how the IsInRole comes back?  Is it coming back True or False when you expect it to?